# С++. Как отсортировать массив, что бы сначала шли отрицательные числа на убывание, потом положительные числа на убывание?

Tags: c++, массивы, функции

Мне дано массив из 20 рандомных элементов, значение которых от -100 до 100.
Требуется отсортировать массив так, что бы сначала шли отрицательные элементы на убывание, потом положительные, так же на убывание. При чём очень желательно не использовать встроенные методы сортировки. Также требуется использовать для создания массива свою функцию, а для сортировки - свою. В main() нужно только вывести результаты.
Пробовал некоторые способы, но программа просто вылетала, даже описывать их нет смысла.
Вот код для обычной сортировки по убыванию. Сделано в Qt Creator

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

void crArr1(int mas[], int &size);
void masPrint(int *mas, int &size);
void sortArr1(int mas[], int &size);
void masSortPrint(int *mas, int &size);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    int size;
    int *mas;
    masPrint(mas, size);
    masSortPrint(mas, size);
    return a.exec();
}

void crArr1(int mas[], int &size){
    size = 20;
    int i = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=0; i<size; i++){
        mas[i] = rand()%201-100;
    }
}

void masPrint(int *mas, int &size){
    crArr1(mas, size);
    cout <<"\nFirst random array:"<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        cout << mas[i];
        if(i<size-1) cout <<" ";
    }
    cout <<endl;
}

void sortArr1(int mas[], int &size){
    size = 20;
    for (int i=0; i<size-1; i++){
        int smInd = i;
        for(int j=i+1; j<size; j++){
            if(mas[j] > mas[smInd])
                smInd = j;
        }
        int tmp = mas[i];
        mas[i] = mas[smInd];
        mas[smInd] = tmp;
    }
}

void masSortPrint(int *mas, int &size){
    sortArr1(mas, size);
    cout << "\nDescending sorted array:"<<endl;
    for (int index=0; index < size; index++)
        cout << mas[index] << ' ';
    cout <<endl;
}
```

Comment: Ну нет, так не пойдёт. Задача несложная, требует только аккуратного написания условия сравнения (компаратора). Так что показывайте свою сортировку, чтобы она работала обычным образом, а дальше подшаманим

Comment: А программа вылетала, потому что вы не выделили память под массив, а уже записываете туда значения.

Comment: Дело в том, что эта программа работает и не вылетает, а как сделать сортировку: сначала отрицательные на убывание, потом положительные на убывание, я не знаю

Comment: Вариант 1 - сначала сортируете по возрастанию весь массив. Потом делаете реверс отдельно отрицательных чисел и отдельно положительных чисел.

Comment: Вариант 2 - делаете сортировку по убыванию всего массива, потом меняете местами отрицательные и положительные числа (копируете положительные в отдельный массив, копируете отрицательные числа в начало массива, копируете положительные числа обратно в массив после отрицательных).

Comment: @DmitryK С реверсом хорошая идея.

Comment: вы выделить память забыли : `void crArr1(int* &mas, int &size){size = 20;mas = new int[size];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, у вас сделана сортировка выбором. Принцип упорядочения задаётся здесь:

```
if(mas[j] > mas[smInd])
```

Как его надо изменить?
Если оба числа положительные, то менять ничего не надо.
Если оба отрицательные, то тоже ничего менять не надо.
А вот если знаки разные, то результат сравнения должен быть обратным.

Раз диапазон значений ограничен, то умножение не вызовет переполнения, и мы можем записать

```
if(mas[j] * mas[smInd] * (mas[j] - mas[smInd]) > 0)
```